# Create mysql DB with PHP through cPanel and import *.sql file

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I want to create a DB for each user who wants to register to my Web-app. When i try this local everything perfectly works. A User can register with his email and pw. A DB is created and a import.sql file is imported so that the DB created for the User is empty on data but the tables and realtioships are given.

My Host uses cPanel and phpMyAdmin to create DB and db-user. I want to do this with php like i do it local. Does anyone have an idea how i get this done?

I've already searched and tryed stuff out but nothing works for me.

If possible some explanations on cPanel maybe would be enough.

Comment: No, you don't want to create a separate database for each user.  It will create an application that is extremely difficult to maintain.

Comment: why would that be extremely difficult to maintain? @user2182349

Comment: What if you decide to change the database schema in the future?  You would have to modify every database.  How would you administer the application - such as searching for a user when they complain they can't log in? What if the hosting company limits you to 10 databases?  Finally, **no one does this** because it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user2182349 you are right, did not think about that .. what would you recommend me now ?

Comment: Create a database with different tables.  One of the tables can store your users, so each user has a record in the database.  You will probably find the database schema you have can be extended for this.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php
            require("xmlapi.php"); // this can be downlaoded from https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/blob/master/xmlapi.php
            $xmlapi = new xmlapi("cpanlel host name");   
            $xmlapi->set_port( 2083 );   
            $xmlapi->password_auth('cpanel username','cpanel passsword');    
            $xmlapi->set_debug(0);//output actions in the error log 1 for true and 0 false 

            $cpaneluser='cpanel username';
            $databasename="something";
            $databaseuser="database username";
            $databasepass= 'database password';

            //create database    
            $createdb = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adddb", array($databasename));   
            //create user 
            $usr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduser", array($databaseuser, $databasepass));   
            //add user 
            $addusr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, 'Mysql', 'adduserdb', array('' . $databasename . '', '' . $databaseuser . '', 'all'));
            ?>
```

Using the above code you will be able to create new database, add new user to database and give all access to user on database.